# Insert error on update

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a good amount of experience with MVC but can't seem to figure what is going wrong here. 
I'm trying to update the user's model but for some reason what should be an update is attempting to execute as an insert.

Edit: I'm using [this starter site](https://github.com/andrewelkins/Laravel-4-Bootstrap-Starter-Site) for Laravel which uses Ardent

```
$user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
$user->recipient_id = "xxxxxxxxx";
if ($user->save()) {
    return true;
} else {
    print_r($user->errors()->all()); die();
}
```

The above outputs

```
Array (
    [0] => The username has already been taken.
    [1] => The email has already been taken.
    [2] => The password confirmation does not match.
)
```

Any help would be really appreciated! I have a feeling its something trivial...

Comment: You are calling a method $user->save(), what does that method do. How you differentiate the insert and update methods inside your save method?

Comment: Are you using `Ardent`?

Comment: The problem lies in your `unique` rules that are applied on update too. So depending on how you validate your input (Ardent, validation service, manually in the controller) you need to refine are remove those rules when updating or use different set of rules for `create` and `update`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually while validating it uses rules of the User Model class.
This happens because use of these lines in models.

```
public $autoHydrateEntityFromInput = true;    // hydrates on new entries' validation
public $forceEntityHydrationFromInput = true; // hydrates whenever validation is called
```

What you have to do is to change the rules dynamically.

```
$user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
$user->recipient_id = "xxxxxxxxx";
$user::$rules['username'] = 'required|regex:/^[a-zA-Z\- ]+$/|unique:users,username,'.$user_id;
$user::$rules['email'] = 'required|email|unique:users,email,'.$user_id;
$user::$rules['password'] = 'required';
//this will ignore current username and email
if ($user->save()) {
    return true;
} else {
    print_r($user->errors()->all()); die();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked! It seems as though this should happen by default with ->update() or something. Looks like there was a pull request to do so but not sure if it was ever merged https://github.com/laravelbook/ardent/pull/79